# ClassNotFoundException of NIO using Tomcat 7 and Java 7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

I build a web project in Eclipse Kepler with Apache Tomcat 7.0.47.

While running on server, it causes `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.file.Paths` as below.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/file/Paths
    at ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.file.Paths
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 12 more
```

It worked well before I invite this new feature of Java 7. Could anyone give me some suggest to figure out what's going on here please?

Comment: Are there any old versions of jdk in your server?! The path which contains java.exe may include that old version.

Comment: **YES!** But I have deleted it (jdk 6) from path in system environment variables. Should I uninstall it?

Comment: uninstalling is not required. But it is obvious that your Tomcat 7.0  still uses the jdk 6. There are to paths system path and user path. Check both of them.

Comment: Alireza Fattahi! Thank you so much! It turns out to be me using tomcat with jdk 6 all the time. Problem fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling older version is not required.

But it is obvious that your Tomcat 7.0 still uses the jdk 6. There are two paths system path and user path. Check both of them.